# How is one able to delete an vm-image

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I do not find a function to delete an existing VM-Image at the IBM-Bluemix-Console.

I searched the whole console and do not find any way to do this.

How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a virtual server image by using the Python OpenStackClient command `openstack image delete`. In order to run this command, you first need to have the OpenStack client set up. [These instructions](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_setup_cli) tell you how to set up the OpenStackClient in the Bluemix environment.

See [this topic in the Bluemix docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_deleteimage_cli) for details on how to use the `openstack image delete` command.